# Complex 1i doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I try to follow example from that website:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

But I get other results. For example for that code:

```
std::complex<double> z1 = 1i * 1i;     // imaginary unit squared
std::cout << "i * i = " << z1 << '\n';
```

It works great, I get in the console:

> i * i = (-1,0)

But other example:

```
std::complex<double> z3 = std::exp(1i * M_PI); // Euler's formula
std::cout << "exp(i * pi) = " << z3 << '\n';
```

I get error: call to 'exp' is ambiguous

So I tried that one:

```
double PI = std::acos(-1);
std::complex<double> z3 = pow(M_E, 1i * PI); // Euler's formula
std::cout << "exp(i * pi) = " << z3 << '\n';
```

And now I get no error, but the results are not expected:

> exp(i * pi) = (1,0)

It should be minus 1, instead plus 1. Why it doesn't work for me. Please help.

Also other example:

```
std::complex<double> z4 = 1i + 1i; // Euler's formula
std::cout << "i + i = " << z4 << '\n';
```

I expect result: (0,2)
But I get: (0,0)

I tried that code in xCode and in CodeBlocks. The same results.
For any help thanks in advance.

My whole code looks like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1);

    std::complex<double> z1 = 1i * 1i; // it's OK
    std::cout << "i * i = " << z1 << '\n'; // it gives: i * i = (-1.0,0.0)
/*
    std::complex<double> z2 = std::pow(1i, 2); // That gives error: call to 'pow' is ambiguous'
    std::cout << "pow(i, 2) = " << z2 << '\n';

    double PI = std::acos(-1);
    std::complex<double> z3 = std::exp(1i * PI); // That gives error: call to 'exp' is ambiguous'
    std::cout << "exp(i * pi) = " << z3 << '\n';
*/

    double PI = std::acos(-1);
    std::complex<double> z4 = pow(M_E, 1i * PI);
    std::cout << "exp(i * pi) = " << z4 << '\n'; // That gives: exp(i * pi) = (1.0,0.0). Should be (-1.0,0.0)

    std::complex<double> z5 = 1. + 2i, z6 = 1. - 2i;
    std::cout << "(1+2i)*(1-2i) = " << z5*z6 << '\n'; // That gives: (1+2i)*(1-2i) = (1.0,0.0). Should be (5.0,0.0)

    std::complex<double> z7 = 1i + 1i;
    std::cout << "i + i = " << z7 << '\n'; // That gives: i + i = (0.0,0.0). Should be (0.0,2.0)

    return 0;
}
```

So as you can see, nothing complicated. Of course it's in main.cpp file, and in my project there are no other files.

Comment: all those code fragments work as expected when extended to minimal complete examples: [i * i = (-1,0)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xBnBMgt1rNnkS3il), [exp(i * pi) = (-1,1.22465e-16)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2j7q1uotIhVmN5uX), and [i + i = (0,2)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iHnBA02Nq6NdgTll).

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Like Cubbi points out, there is nothing wrong with those snippets in isolation. You may have done something funny in the code that precedes it, but we can't tell you if the example isn't complete.

Comment: Please see my answer to see my code, because comments are too short.

Comment: Hey Cubbi, thanks for reply, I see on the website you linked everything works fine, but on my computer in xCode and in CodeBlock it doesn't work properly.

Comment: You look to be missing a `using namespace std::literals;`, so something funky is going on to allow any of that to compile

Comment: Hmm, actually I removed `using namespace std::literals;` because it gave me error. Now I don't have acces to my computer, but as I remember error was something like: using namespace require name of namespace. I am not sure it it was exactly like that, but the sense is like that.