# Return array with const number of members

Tags: c++, arrays, complex-numbers, multiple-return-values

I wonder how to write function that returns array with constant number of members. Does it make a sense at all?
I know I can do something like that:

```
float* WojtekEQgraph::_Wk_N(float k)
{
    float comp[2];
    comp[0] = cos(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k); // Real number
    comp[1] = sin(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k); // Imag number

    return comp;
}
```

And it returns array with two members. But actually "return" commend expect pointer to array and no matter how many members it has.
But if in some unpredictable way there will be

`float comp[3]` or `float comp[1]`
I want `return comp;` would give me error.
How can I do that?

I tried that:

```
float[2] WojtekEQgraph::_Wk_N(float k)
{
    float comp[2];
    comp[0] = cos(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k); // Real number
    comp[1] = sin(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k); // Imag number

    return comp;
}
```

But it doesn't work. For any help thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::array<float,2>`

Comment: You may also want to consider creating a `struct` or `class` to represent complex numbers. Down the road it will make life simpler.

Comment: @lakeweb there is already `std::complex`, no need to reinvent the projective plane

Comment: Also there is already `std::polar` to do what this function does

Comment: @M.M: I've already given an answer with that...

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried to use complex but had problems with it, please see my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116370/complex-1i-doesnt-work-properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return an array object, the C++ standard library spells it as [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). So applying it to your example:

```
std::array<float, 2> WojtekEQgraph::_Wk_N(float k)
{
    std::array<float, 2> comp;
    comp[0] = cos(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k); // Real number
    comp[1] = sin(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k); // Imag number

    return comp;
}
```

Would do it. Other advantages include the lack of dangling references and the need to deal with messy memory allocation. A short and sweet aggregate.

There's also another answer if you are dealing with complex numbers. Don't re-invent the wheel, and use [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) instead.

Comment: Agree but he should study first what pointers are and how they work

Comment: @Moia - No, the OP better study them later. Value semantics are extremely intuitive and easy to grasp. Array-to-pointer conversions are a tangential subject that slows the study pace down for little reason.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Your answer is fine, but this comment of yours is golden.

Comment: @einpoklum - I can't take credit. If you haven't seen it yet, I highly recommend [this talk by Kate Gregory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) from CppCon 2015.

Comment: Fine, but it really seems it doesn't know what array[2] means.

Comment: @Moia - What is the *it* that doesn't know? I'm not saying one should not study arrays. I'm saying one doesn't need to learn C just to learn C++. One can learn C++, keep their sanity, and pick up the historically significant parts later. Just because we had this burden placed on us early in our studies, doesn't mean it's the *best* way to learn. I recommend the talk I linked to, to you as well.

Comment: I never thought he should learn C before, and I'm strongly against C masked of C++. This a speculation of your :)

Comment: @Moia - I didn't speculate anything about you. I expressed my opinion about presentation of C++ material. Since it seems we are not in a disagreement, I bid you a continued good evening (or good day, depending on your time zone).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried to use complex but had problems with it, please see my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116370/complex-1i-doesnt-work-properly

Answer (score 2):

#### Returning a fixed-length array is usually a sign of a missing  abstraction

While @StoryTeller's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119060/1593077) is the correct one for what you asked *literally*, it can also be said that what you really want to return is not an "array of 2 floats" - you want to return a complex number.

Now, unlike @StefanLechner's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119140/1593077), I suggest you use the standard library's class for complex numbers, specified with floats to fit your current precision choice:

```
std::complex<float> WojtekEQgraph::_Wk_N(float k)
{
    return {
        cos(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k), // Real number
        sin(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k), // Imag number
    };
}
```

and in your even-more-specific case, just do:

```
std::complex<float> WojtekEQgraph::_Wk_N(float k)
{
    return std::polar<float>( 1.0f, -2.0f * double_Pi * k );
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for the named constructor alone. There really is no comparing the improved version to original.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns a pointer to a local variable, which very likely yields undefined behaviour:

```
float comp[2];
...
return comp;
```

An immediate answer to your question would be to use a `std::array<float, 2>` data type.

However, it seems as if you want to "abuse" an array for expressing a complex number. I'd suggest to introduce a class and return an object of this class instead:

```
struct ComplexNumber{
  float real;
  float imaginary;
}

ComplexNumber WojtekEQgraph::_Wk_N(float k) {
  ComplexNumber c;
  c.real = ...
  c.imaginary = ...
  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using c++11 one solution would be to use std::array

```
std::array< float, 2 > WojtekEQgraph::_Wk_N(float k)
{
    std::array< float, 2 > comp;
    comp[0] = cos(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k); // Real number
    comp[1] = sin(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k); // Imag number

    return comp;
}
```

An alternative is to pass your array into the method:

```
void WojtekEQgraph::_Wk_N(float k, float comp[2])
{
    comp[0] = cos(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k); // Real number
    comp[1] = sin(-2.0f * double_Pi * (float)k); // Imag number
}

float comp[2];
obj._Wk_N(0, comp);
```